# ORA 00936 Missing Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, select, syntax-error

I have looked through the site and cannot find an answer to my question, many close but none the same.  I am trying to select data from two tables and join five.  The three which I am not selecting information for are publisher, order_items, and book_order.  They are just the tables in the ERD which are in line.  I keep on getting ORA 00936: Missing expression on my FROM line.  But I have no idea what is causing it.  all of the tables are represented accurately, the only thing that is different is the TO_CHAR statement in the SELECT line.  I think that may be the problem.

```
SELECT book_customer.firstname, book_customer.lastname, 
TO_CHAR(book_order.orderdate,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "Order Date",
  FROM book_customer, book_order, order_items, books, publisher
    WHERE (book_customer.customerid = book_order.customerid) 
      AND (book_order.orderid = order_items.orderid)
      AND (order_items.bookid = books.bookid)
      AND (books.pubid = publisher.pubid)
      AND (publisher.publishername = 'printing with us');
```

Comment: There is a comma before FROM.

Comment: You should learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax, although that has nothing to do with this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a redundant comma (`,`) before your `from` clause:

```
SELECT book_customer.firstname, book_customer.lastname, 
TO_CHAR(book_order.orderdate,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "Order Date" -- Comma removed here
  FROM book_customer, book_order, order_items, books, publisher
    WHERE (book_customer.customerid = book_order.customerid) 
      AND (book_order.orderid = order_items.orderid)
      AND (order_items.bookid = books.bookid)
      AND (books.pubid = publisher.pubid)
      AND (publisher.publishername = 'printing with us');
```